# Allowed memory size of Symfony FlattenException.php

Tags: php, symfony

I have a 2.7.10 Symfony app with PHP 5.6 on a Debian 8 server.

I customized my error pages (400, 500).

When I return

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException();
```

in my own controller, my error page is correctly rendering.

When I try to access a route which doesn't exist, I got a 500 error with blank page.

In my apache error.log, I got a

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/acheter-francais-org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FlattenException.php on line 284
```

I tried to increase memory_limit to 256M, 512M, 1G...but without success.
I also tried to remove my vendor folder and composer.lock and reinstalled all with composer install, but without success too.

Thank you per advance.

Comment: did you try [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)? it should show you more details when enabled.

Comment: Thanks to Xdebug, I resolved my issue. I had some errors which were not shown without Xdebug (Apache, Twig and error pages).

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I will be thankful if you accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install and enable [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). It should give you more details on real errors, pointing you to the parts of code where it actually fails.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing same error within Symfony 3.2.8, PHP 7, MySQL 5.7.

Open your web/app.php and enable debug to see the error:

Replace:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

With:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Then you should see some errors to start debugging...

In my case it was a wrong SQL statement because of MySQL 5.7. There's a ticket opened here: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5622